# Checking button text matches a certain string in Nightwatch.js

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, nightwatch.js

I'm having a heck of a time trying to write a test where I check that text on a button matches a certain string. I tried ".valueContains", ".attributeContains" and got blank or null, and I've tried getText(), but that only seems to return an object.

I feel like it's something obvious I'm missing, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you have written so far in your question, I am wondering if there is there a reason you cannot use .containsText?

```
.waitForElementVisible('.yourclass', this.timeout)
.assert.containsText('.yourclass', 'Text of Button you expect to match')
```

http://nightwatchjs.org/api#assert-containsText

Comment: This turned out to be the correct way to do it-- the actual problem was the automation was checking the button before the text could load. So I added a pause to make sure the page caught up.

Answer (score 0):

Without actually looking at the code its little difficult to predict whats going on. However all of the methods in selenium return a promise, so you need to wait for it to resolve.

```
function async getTextOfButton() {
  const element = await driver.findElement(By.className('item-class'));
  const text = await element.getText();
}
```

If you are not using async/await you could do

```
driver.findElement(By.className('item-class')).then(function(element) {
  element.getText().then(function(text) {
      console.log(text);
  });
});
```

Comment: It turned out it was a completely different problem (see above), but thank you for the reply.

I actually need to learn more about await-- there are other parts of my code that could benefit from it.